# Xterm configuration

Tags: vim, xterm

I use xterm emulator in my archlinx, the Xresource configuration is this:

```
XTerm*locale: true
Xterm*faceName: Monaco:antialias=true
XTerm*faceNameDoublesize: WenQuanYi micro hei:antialias=true
XTerm*background: black
XTerm*foreground: gray
```

I am a Chinese, so I set `XTerm*faceNameDoublesize` to Chinese font, but when I used the `vim-airline plugin`, the symbols in the status line can't display like this:

[image]

and this:

```
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
```

(The symbols above this can't be displayed in the xterm)

I used another terminal emulator to do this and it was ok, so I think my xterm is wrong, but I can't find it out why.

Comment: It seems like problem with fonts. Try [this](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/master/installation.html#patched-fonts) and then put `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1` in your .vimrc. I hope it will help.

Comment: `uxterm` doesn't support the correct characters by default?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that `xterm` is using a single font (rather than a font set), and if the special characters are missing from the font, those will not display as intended.

However, that was not the question posed here.  Rather, it was "How can I make the plugin work as intended".

The comment about `g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1`, is a clue but incomplete.  Referring to the [vim-airline FAQ](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ), we find a vague statement:

> Adding let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1 to your vimrc will automatically populate the g:airline_symbols dictionary with the proper font glyphs for various symbols.

I found a few related questions on this topic, but all were cut/paste from the FAQ, so I will not mention them.

Actually, reading the source code ([`init.vim`](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/blob/master/autoload/airline/init.vim)) gives a better explanation (the FAQ entry is not useful).  What the source code does is *initialize* the plugin to Unicode or ASCII values for the various special characters, depending on the `g:airline_powerline_fonts` variable. In OP's question, he has apparently set values after the plugin initializes, which is too late for the variable-setting to be useful.  For proper integration with the plugin, his `.vimrc` should do something similar to the plugin, taking this variable into account.